# Delegate not called at UIBarItem tap

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates

The delegate method is not called tapping the `UIBarItem`. I went through so many advices all are same what I wrote.

I tried according to advices, no solution. Everywhere given call the delegate. I did each and everything.

```
class ViewController: CommonClass,Mydelegate {

    var vc = CommonClass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        vc = CommonClass(nibName: "CommonClass", bundle: nil)
        initializeCartBarButton()
        vc.delegate = self
        print( (vc.delegate))
    }

    func testing() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

class CommonClass: UIViewController {

    var delegate:Mydelegate?

    func initializeCartBarButton() {
        let cartBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        cartBarButton.title = "cart"
        cartBarButton.target = self
        cartBarButton.action = Selector("goToCart")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cartBarButton;

    }

    func goToCart() {
        print("hi")
        if self.delegate?.testing() != nil {
            self.delegate?.testing()

        }else {
            print(self.delegate)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did "hi" message prints at touch?

Comment: yes, but if condition failing

Comment: Next print is "nil"?

Comment: how does your MyDelegate looks like?

Comment: @ShadowOf yes.  custom delegate that, just printing hello(not printing).

Comment: First problem that I see - invokation of `initializeCartBarButton`, why it happends in `ViewController` instance, not in `CommonClass`: `vc.initializeCartBarButton()`? But if "hi" printed, then action initialized. Where? And how you present `CommonClass` controller on screen? Probably you should update your code with more relevant.

Comment: So is `vc` a nested `viewController`, or is `ViewController` supposed to subclass `CommonClass`?

Comment: @ShadowOf viewcontroller is inheritance of common class

Comment: I see. But where do you present your `vc` on screen?

Comment: didload in viewcontroller

Comment: If you think that you presented it by creation, you are wrong. If you didn't show us some parts of function - show us.

Comment: @ShadowOfclass ViewController: CommonClass,Mydelegate {
    
    var vc = CommonClass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        vc = CommonClass(nibName: "CommonClass", bundle: nil)
        initializeCartBarButton()
        vc.delegate = self
        print( (vc.delegate))
    }
    
    func testing() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

Comment: please use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39484506/edit) button at bottom of your post if you wish show us big parts of code. And this is just same code. You are not presenting new controller on screen.

Comment: @Pavankumar. please check my answer and reply. if you want, i will add the sample project..

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @Mr.UB no solution i got

Answer (score 0):

What I saw is:

1. `CommonClass` Inherits `UIViewController`.
2. `ViewController` Inherits `CommonClass`.
3. Means View Controller can Directly call `CommonClass` Methods.
4. You can direcly call `goToCart()` method from `ViewController`.

Hence, there is no need to use Delegate Pattern to call methods of `CommonClass`.

Comment: Let me know, if missed something regarding your application's working logic.

Answer (score 0):

A sample example to demonstrate using custom delegates:

### ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit


protocol Mydelegate
{
    func testing()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var delegate:Mydelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        goToCart()
    }

    func goToCart() {
        print("hi")
        if delegate?.testing() != nil {
            delegate?.testing()

        }else {
            print(delegate)
        }
    }
}
```

### ViewController2.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, Mydelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func testing() {
        print("hello")
    }

    @IBAction func goButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let vc: ViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewC") as! ViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        print( (vc.delegate))
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

StoryBoardId for ViewController is "viewC"